# Fitting contents of a webpage between the top and the browser status bar

Tags: html, browser, applet

I have an html page with an embedded applet.   Currently the content of the applet extends beyond the status bar.   The user has to scroll, using the browser scrollbar to see the bottom area of the applet.     I want the applet to display in the browser so that it does not extend beyond the status bar, regardless of how the user sizes the browser .  I'm not sure how to approach this problem.    I believe I need to do something in the HTML, but what?

Thank you,

Elliott

Here is the portion of the code where the applet is embedded:

```
 <div style="width:100%; height:89%; margin-left:0px;>
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width="100%" height="90%">
<tr style="height:100%;">   
    <td VALIGN="TOP">   
       <div  style="visibility:visible; background:white; foreground:black; font-        
 size:200%; width:100%; height:10%; margin-left:100px; margin-top:5px; margin-
  right:100px;     text-align:center; cursor:wait;" id="msgdiv">
            <p> Please wait while The Application Loads </p>
        </div>
        <div align="center" style="cursor:wait; height:100%;"  id="divapp" 
  name="divapp" >
            <APPLET NAME="RevApp2" CODE="RevApp2.class" id="myapplet" name="myapplet"  
  style="visibility:hidden;"
              ARCHIVE ="CoderDx.jar,xpp3-1.1.3.4.C.jar,xml-apis.jar,jcommon-
  1.0.16.jar,jfreechart-1.0.13.jar,MultiSplit.jar,balloontip-
 1.1.1.jar,artificialmed.jar" WIDTH=99% HEIGHT=100%>
                <PARAM NAME = USERID VALUE = "#DxWebTemplate" />
                <PARAM NAME = URL VALUE = "#IPAddress" />
                <PARAM NAME = PATHNAME VALUE = "#PathName" />
                <PARAM NAME = SessionID VALUE = "#SessionID" />
                <PARAM NAME = Role VALUE = "#Role" />
            </APPLET>
    </div>  
    </TD>
</TR>  
  </table>
 </div>
```

changing the height of the div, shortens the applet and allows it to fit into the browser display without scrolling but the underlying webpage underneath is still the same.   And for users with really large monitors, I am unable to take advantage of the available screen space.     Ideally it is the web page that should adjust to the browser window, not the div's within the webpage.

Comment: can you post the code of where you insert the applet?

Comment: `<APPLET NAME="RevApp2" CODE="RevApp2.class" id="myapplet" name="myapplet" ..` is the name of this applet `RevApp2` or `myapplet`?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily resize the element that contains the applet using the `style` attribute - as in `style="height:100%; width:100%;"`

*However* the layout and size of elements *within* the applet is controlled via java source code. If you want to edit that, it's time to break out your IDE of choice. If that doesn't make sense, might I suggest [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), and a good read at [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/newtojava/overview/gettingstarted-jsp-138588.html)

Comment: I think that what I'm looking for is that the entire web page fit between the top and the status bar.    Then, the applet will resize based on those parameters.    The problem is that the web page extends below the status bar.   That is the problem I need to solve.